# Не работает код на C

Tags: c

```
#include <math.h> // подключение библиотеки математических функций
#include <stdio.h> // подключение библиотеки функций ввода-вывода данных
#include <windows.h> // подключение библиотеки функций, связанных с ОС Windows

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); //Настройка консоли Windows для корректной работы с русскими символами
    printf("Введите значение переменной n="); //Вывод на экран текстовой строки
    int n; // Объявление переменной "n" целочисленного типа
    scanf("%f",&n); // Запрос пользователю ввести целочисленное число с последующей записью введенного числа в качестве значения переменной n
    int i;
    int a;
    a=0;
    i=1;
    do
    {
     i=i+1;
     printf("Введите значение переменной a(%u)=",i);
     scanf("%f",&a);
    }
    while (i<=n);
    return 0;
}
```

Не завершается, когда i становится больше n.

Comment: А выведите значение n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что вы хотите...

```
int n; // Объявление переменной "n" целочисленного типа
scanf("%f",&n);
```

Вводите как `float` - вот и получается `n` совершенно нелепым: представления в памяти `int` и `float` кардинально различны...

Вот такой код на грани фола — гуру в стандарте заплюют, но он хорошо показывает, каким становится `n` при таком вводе: https://ideone.com/Hsyv57

Comment: А какое именно различие? Я понимаю, что вопрос Вам покажется глупым, но всё же я только учусь) Не могли бы разъяснить по подробнее?

Comment: Посмотрите https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB  Для целых же чисел биты, грубо говоря, соответствуют 0 и 1 двоичной записи числа.